# downloading m3u8 format using ffmpeg in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8, android-ffmpeg

I want to download a `m3u8 hls` video on android.
i am using this `https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java` github project.
my code run perfect with some file like this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=560000,RESOLUTION=560x320
chunklist_w1370359847_b560000.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=280000,RESOLUTION=280x160
chunklist_w1370359847_b280000.m3u8
```

but when i want to get some others like

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=307200
http://example.com/hls.m3u8?mwk=8337411690192241322178516954798640895&s=67456834233263474843895996561490854813
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3584000
http://example.com/hls.m3u8?mwk=8337411690192241322178516954798640895&s=67917168793981422148373769951238010028
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2457600
http://example.com/hls.m3u8?mwk=8337411690192241322178516954798640895&s=58718242671779879146351545392642701787
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1228800
http://example.com/hls.m3u8?mwk=8337411690192241322178516954798640895&s=76033982771160137261725364336240341356
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=614400
http://example.com/hls.m3u8?mwk=8337411690192241322178516954798640895&s=8799167971211576392205612488036401876
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=65536
http://example.com/hls.m3u8?mwk=8337411690192241322178516954798640895&s=84365905843905491151101581870671639752
```

, i received `Protocol not found` error.
my url is http and i use bellow command

```
String.format("-i %s -acodec %s -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec %s %s", mM3u8Url, "copy", "copy", dir.toString() + "/" + mContentId + ".mp4");
```

Comment: can you please tell me how you download hls video in android?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your m3u8 is encrypt.Could you find "#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128"  in your m3u8 which mean you need decode it.

Comment: No
absolutely there is no problem with encryption
because i can play it with VLC Player

Comment: Because VLC can automatic decryption m3u8.                                                     I meat the same error,because the m3u8 was encypted by AES-128.             First,you need make sure,whether is encypted,try to find "#EXT-X-KEY:"         Then,find a way to decode.